# images on canvas are being stack on each other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using a for loop to put several images on a canvas.
My for loop generates positions with

```
         var posx= i*(50);
         var posy = i*(50);

         img.src = "./path/img.png"; 
         img.onload = function() {
         var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');

             canvas.drawImage(this, posx, posy);
}
```

even though I am changing my posx and posy , all of the images are being drawn at the same location.
I printed to the console their posx, posy , and they are different at each iteration.
any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a scope issue

You need to create a closure to keep all the calls from using the same (*the last*) `posx` and `posy` values.

Something like

```
img.onload = (function(x,y) { return function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
        canvas.drawImage(this, x, y);
    };
  })(posx, posy);
```

and it is also wise to use set the `src` of the image object after you define its `onload` to avoid issues with cached images.

Comment: Hey could you either explain what is the nature of the scope problem, or suggest a link where I can read about it?. I am also asking because while drawImage is working properties that i set such as                  this.style.height = "50px"; are not working , and I am assuming this is a scope issue as well

Comment: Have a read at http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/